# AngularJS Help Text on Pristine (with focus)

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a requirement that when a text box is **pristine**, and the user clicks inside it, that help text appears.

```
 <input name="Country" ng-model="Country">
 <p ng-show="form.Country.$pristine && ?????">Enter your country</a>
```

Not sure how to get the "**has focus**" as well for the **ng-show**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use [`ngFocus`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus) for this, like so:

```
<input name="Country" ng-model="Country" ng-focus="focused = true">
<p ng-show="form.Country.$pristine && focused">Enter your country</a>
```